# ORA-00984: column not allowed here - error at line 1 sql

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, string-constant

```
SQL>CREATE TABLE student(ID INT, Name VARCHAR(20), Percentage INT, 
                         Location VARCHAR(20), DateOfBirth DATE);

SQL> INSERT INTO student(ID, Name, Percentage, Location, DateOfBirth) 
     VALUES(1, "Manthan Koli", 79, "Delhi", "2003-08-20");
```

Getting this error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

Comment: Use single quotes for string literals, e.g. `'Manthan Koli'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Oracle, it is a **single quote** you use to enclose strings (as specified in the SQL standard).

Apart from that, Oracle recommends us to use `VARCHAR2` instead of `VARCHAR`.

Finally, when inserting dates, don't insert strings - use date literal (as my example shows), or `TO_DATE` function with appropriate format model.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE student
  2  (
  3     ID            INT,
  4     Name          VARCHAR2 (20),
  5     Percentage    INT,
  6     Location      VARCHAR2 (20),
  7     DateOfBirth   DATE
  8  );

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO student (ID,
  2                       Name,
  3                       Percentage,
  4                       Location,
  5                       DateOfBirth)
  6       VALUES (1,
  7               'Manthan Koli',
  8               79,
  9               'Delhi',
 10               DATE '2003-08-20');

1 row created.

SQL>
```